# добавление функции параметром

Tags: python, функции

Есть некая функция

```
def get_palindrome_digits(n):
    return True if str(n)[::-1] == str(n) else False
```

к примеру такая.
Подскажите, как можно добавить параметром эту функцию в генератор, чтобы она помечала при вызове этого генератора выводимые им числа true/false в зависимости от своего назначения(в данном случае функция определяет палиндромные числа)

```
def prime_numbers_generator(n):
    prime_numbers = []
    for number in range(2, n + 1):
        for prime in prime_numbers:
            if not number % prime:
                break
        else:
            prime_numbers.append(number)
            yield number
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В Питоне практически всё может быть переменной, а значит и параметром, передаваемым в функцию. Включая сами функции:

```
def get_palindrome_digits(n):
    return str(n)[::-1] == str(n)

def palindrome_numbers_generator(n, f):
    for number in range(10, n):
        if f(number): # вызов функции, переданной как параметр
            yield number

for n in palindrome_numbers_generator(100, get_palindrome_digits):
    print(n)
```

Вывод:

```
11
22
33
44
55
66
77
88
99
```

Answer (score 4):

Вы имеете в виду такое решение?

```
def get_palindrome_digits(n):
    return True if str(n)[::-1] == str(n) else False

lst = [11, 12, 22, 33, 34]

res = [get_palindrome_digits(x) for x in lst]
```

res, соответственно, будет

```
[True, False, True, True, False]
```

Comment: можно немножко упростить: `return str(n)[::-1] == str(n)`  -  результат сравнения уже объект типа `bool` ;)

Comment: Не совсем, сейчас у меня с моим кодом фильтрация происходит вот так:for number in prime_numbers_generator(n=10000):
print(number, get_palindrome_digits(number), sep=' '). Но мне нужно передать функцию как параметр к генератору

Comment: чтобы такой же результат был при выводе: prime_numbers_generator(n = 1000, func = get_palindrome_digits)